# POWER QUERY - Payload in a json request with invalid format

Tags: json, post, get, powerquery

I'm developing a request in Power BI's Power Query, and I came across the following error:

> Payload in a json request with invalid format.

Follow the code:

```
let

URL1 = "example/login",
POST = [
    #"Content-Type" = "application/json",
    Token = "TOKEN HERE",
    Appkey = "APPKEY HERE",
    Username = "USER HERE",
    Password = "PASS HERE"
    ],

postData = Text.ToBinary(""),
Resposta = Web.Contents(
    URL1,
    [
        Headers = POST,
        Content = postData
    ]
),
Fonte1 = Json.Document(Resposta),
BearerToken = Fonte1[bearerToken],

Body = "{""serviceName"": ""example.loadRecords"",
        ""requestBody"": {
            ""dataSet"": {
                ""rootEntity"": ""example"",
                ""includePresentationFields"": ""S"",
                ""offsetPage"": ""0"",
                ""criteria"": {
                    ""expression"": {
                        ""$"": ""(this.example= ? )""
                    },
                    ""parameter"": {
                        ""$"": ""01/08/2023"",
                        ""type"": ""D""
                    }
                },
                ""entity"": {
                    ""fieldset"": {
                        ""list"": ""example,example,example,example,example,example,example""
                    }
                }
            }
        }"
        ,

URL2 = "example/gateway/v1/example/example.sbr?example=example.example&outputType=json",
GET = Web.Contents(
    URL2,
        [
            Headers = [
                #"Content-Type"="application/json",
                Authorization="Bearer "&BearerToken
                ],
            Content = Text.ToBinary(Body)
        ]),

Fonte2 = Json.Document(GET),
Table1 = Record.ToTable(Fonte2)
in 
Table1
```

Can anyone help me in this case?

I tried to change the format how the body is typed, and the headers of the GET.

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, please mark the answer as having solved your question by toggling the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

Body does not output a valid JSON

```
{"serviceName": "example.loadRecords",
    "requestBody": {
        "dataSet": {
            "rootEntity": "example",
            "includePresentationFields": "S",
            "offsetPage": "0",
            "criteria": {
                "expression": {
                    "$": "(this.example= ? )"
                },
                "parameter": {
                    "$": "01/08/2023",
                    "type": "D"
                }
            },
            "entity": {
                "fieldset": {
                    "list": "example,example,example,example,example,example,example"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tested by saving as a text file and trying to bring back into Powerquery, as well using JSON validator https://jsonlint.com/

Maybe if you get that correct, it will work